# How do I convert date like '31/06/2013' or '30/02/2013' of datatype varchar in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a column named `next_due_date` datatype `varchar` and in this column some non-existing dates like `31/06/2012` or `30/02/2013` are saved. Because of this I get an error message when I convert it to `date` datatype.

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: That doesn't help. The issue is in determining whether the format is a valid date or not.

Comment: `31/06/2013` - 31st of June ????? Seriously????? This will ***NOT*** work with ***ANY*** date formatting string - it's just an **impossible** date to parse ! Same goes for the 30th of February ....

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`try_parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx) (which is only available on higher SQL version, from 2012 on wards). It checks if a date is valid. If so, it returns the `date`, else `null`.

I think `en-GB` is the culture you need:

```
select try_parse('30/06/2012' as date using 'en-GB') -- returns a valid date

select try_parse('31/06/2012' as date using 'en-GB') -- returns null
```

If you need this on lower platforms, I would suggest to parse it by hand using a procedure. Something like this:

```
BEGIN TRY
     select CONVERT(date,'31/06/2012',103)
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
     select null
END CATCH
```

Comment: That doesn't help. This question is tagged `sql-server-2008`. At any rate, the title says *how do I convert* not *how do I find out if a date is valid*. The question is nonsensical.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: Okay, I updated to include a procedural solution for older versions.

Comment: @Neha: need more help?

Answer (score 2):

If you dates *would be valid* (not something like the **31st of June** or **30th of February** - those dates simply don't exist!), then you could easily use the `CONVERT` function to convert them to `DATE`:

```
DECLARE @DateTable TABLE (DateColumn VARCHAR(20))

-- **VALID** dates - 30th of June, 28th of Feb
INSERT INTO @DateTable(DateColumn) VALUES ('30/06/2012'), ('28/02/2013')

-- easily converted to DATE type using style #104
SELECT DateColumn, CONVERT(DATE, DateColumn, 104)
FROM @DateTable
```

Comment: +One Answers *How do I convert date* as best as possible.